# How to Git push older commit to production?

Tags: git, version-control, push, production

How do I push an older commit to production to see which commit ended up breaking the production. I don't want to modify any of the history I just want to pick a commit that's already in the history, and just push that to production without any complicated detached heads or editing any files.

Why is it so hard and documentation so sparse (either sparse or unnecessarily vague and verbose on how to do very basic intuitive things?

Comment: Without knowing something about how you use git, this question will be hard to answer. Do you just need to whack a particular branch on a production repo to a specific hash?

Comment: no extra branches, no deletion of branches. no extra code or deletion of code. just host and push a previous state. I don't see why that was a concern.

Comment: Well, without knowing how the remote is *used*, it's hard to recommend a good solution. `git` lets you rewrite history, for example, which would be bad news if others rely on being able to pull a consistent history from that same remote. Your comment isn't very helpful, but it sounds like the answer to my question is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

You can use bisect to identify which commit break it, revert, commit and push it.

Answer (score 0):

The fully-specified `git push` syntax is:

```
git push REMOTE LOCAL-BRANCH:REMOTE-BRANCH
```

Replace each piece as necessary for your situation. Something like:

```
git push -f production WORKINGHASH:master
```

Is probably what you're looking for. The `-f` will allow your push to rewrite history on the remote, which will be necessary if you're trying to roll back changes transparently.

Since you were concerned about docs, the [`git push` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) has exactly what you're looking for under the first two paragraphs of the 'options' section:

> `<repository>`:
>   The "remote" repository that is destination of a push operation. This parameter can be either a URL ... or the name of a remote.
>
> `<refspec>...`:
>   Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an ... the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.

The `-f` flag is documented there as well:

> `-f`/`--force`:
>   Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. ... This flag disables these checks ...